# Tensorflow-federated 0.17.0 is totally GPU or GPU and CPU?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I would like to know if new version of TFF (0.17.0) is completely GPU ? because on old version, I find that TFF run CPU and GPU .

Answer (score 1):

TFF `0.17.0` is intended to run on GPU if available, otherwise uses CPU as per the underlying `TensorFlow` pip package. This is inline with https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu :

> If a TensorFlow operation has both CPU and GPU implementations, by default the GPU devices will be given priority when the operation is assigned to a device.

If this is not the case, please open an issue on http://github.com/tensorflow/federated and include the output of `pip freeze`, information about environment including OS, python version, and hardware (what GPUs are present in the system).